# Array contents get randomly changed during runtime

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

I got a class named SolidObject, which contains various pointers, pointing to first array elements:

```
// Member declaration and definition pulled together from .cpp and .h
class SolidObject {
    //I will only use one variable as demonstration, the others behave the same
protected:    
    float* vertices;
public:
    SolidObject(float[] vertices) {
        this->vertices = vertices;
    }    
}
```

For experiments I used to pass hardcoded arrays to the constructor, e.g.

```
float vertices[] {
    -5,0,-5,
    5,0,-5,
    -5,10,-5,
    -5,0,5,
    5,10,-5,
    5,0,5,
    -5,10,5,
    5,10,5
};
SolidObject cube (vertices);
```

Now I'm parsing the values from a Stanford PLY file into `std::vector`'s, which I then pass to the constructor:

```
std::vector<float> vertices;
for (...) {
    vertices.push_back(....);
}
SolidObject cube (&vertices[0]);
```

Using this method, the values pointed to in `cube->vertices` are changing during runtime without any reasons. Here's the GDB watchpoint output for `watch coinObject->vertices[0]`:

This is the first time the WP gets triggered. This is intended, as `vertices` is a NULL pointer when the default (void) constructor is used. coinObject is first defined, then initialized, so this behaviour is expected.

```
Hardware watchpoint 1: coinObject->vertices[0]

Old value = <unreadable>
New value = 0.100000001
0x0000000000409c69 in gameloop (screen=0x689cc0, font=0x84a020)
    at ../gameloop.cpp:386
386     coinObject = SolidObject::fromFile("/home/sebastian/coin.ply");
(gdb) c
Continuing.
```

Now comes the stuff I can't explain to myself:

```
Hardware watchpoint 1: coinObject->vertices[0]

Old value = 0.100000001
New value = 0
0x0000003852c8d4b1 in memset () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hardware watchpoint 1: coinObject->vertices[0]

Old value = 0
New value = 1.40129846e-45
0x00007ffff63df548 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/r600_dri.so
(gdb) c
Continuing.
```

This time it stopped after those two changes, there are times with thousands of changes in `coinObject->vertices[0]`. Sometimes the program even crashes after the first or second change since OpenGL, which uses these arrays, can't find the millionth vertex out of 224. (I use a index array for `glDrawElements`, but this is unimportant for my problem...)

Can anyone explain why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Use `backtrace` when on the watchpoint to see where you are.

Comment: Does the original vector whose address you give to `SolidObject` go out of scope by any chance? In that case, memory allocated by the vector is freed and will get used by other objects, which would explain the changing content. Also, if you push_back vertices after you instantiated `SolidObject` the vector could reallocate its buffer and you'll end up with an invalid pointer.

Comment: I don't understand:  Why do you use a vector but not in the object?

Comment: "Crossing the streams", or mixing pointers to arrays and std::vectors will result in undefined behavior and wasted development time.  See my answer below.

Comment: I created the SolidObject class first, and since OpenGL wants arrays, I used arrays/pointers. Today I made the PLY parser, which uses vectors... And yes, the original vectors get out of scope...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would be safer if you used a `vector` in your object:

```
class SolidObject
{
std::vector<float> vertices;
public:
  SolidObject(const std::vector<float>& original_vertices)
     : vertics(original_vertices)
  {
  }
};
```

**If your `vector` that you pass to your version of `SolidObject` ever resizes, your pointer to the floats is no longer valid and points to garbage.**

Also, why are you reducing your precision by using `float` instead of `double`?

If you want `SolidObject` to use the same vector, you would use a reference as a data member:

```
class SolidObject
{
  std::vector<float>& vertices;
  public:
    SolidObject(std::vector<float>& v)
      : vertices(v)
    {
       // Look, no "this" pointer. :-)
    }
};
```

Comment: One of the comments above asked about the vectors getting out of scope, which indeed happens. Could this be the problem? And yes, I think I will use vectors in SolidObject and only create a pointer to the first element to pass it to OpenGL. Btw. What's your problem with `this->vertices`? I think using the same name for the class member and constructor argument makes the code easier to understand.

Comment: I'm using float, because in my book about OpenGL the author always used float... I didn't really think about whether to use double or float. Besides: The PLY file exported by Blender contains float values, so actually there isn't any loss in precision

Comment: @the_Seppi Yes, this is most likely the problem. When the vector responsible for the memory at address `vertices` goes out of scope, this memory is freed and you have a dangling pointer. The problem is that the way you wrote your SolidObject, it doesn't assume ownership of the memory, so the caller has to make sure the pointer passed to the constructor points to something that stays valid. The alternative would be to reserve your own memory in SolidObject and _copy_ the data to it or to make sure the memory pointed to is not freed if copying is not desired.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews I changed every array in SolidObject to a std::vector. However, I'm now getting the following error when trying to pass a existing vector object to the SolidObject constructor: `no matching function for call to ‘SolidObject::SolidObject(std::vector<float>&)`. The code: `std::vector<float> vertices; for(...) { vertices.push_back(...); }  SolidObject object(vertices);`